# Search HTML data table

Tags: html, file, csv, search

I have some code (as below) that allows me to open and display a csv file in Firefox from a location on my hard drive. I'd like to add a search box so it will filter the list when text is entered. I've seen some other working examples that had the table data stored between tags, but I can't get this to work when it's pulling the data from an external file location. I'm really new to JavaScript and this is a bit over my head so if anyone has any pointers i'd appreciate it..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
}
    tr:hover {background-color:#87CEEB;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">Adult Nursing - Absences Informed</h1>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

    <table id="table">
    <tr class="tr">


    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"all_absences.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
}
    tr:hover {background-color:#87CEEB;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">Adult Nursing - Absences Informed</h1>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" placeholder="Search for names..">

    <table id="table">
    <tr class="tr">


    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
var searchKey = "";
function myFunction(e){
    searchKey = e.value;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"all_absences.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
        if(!cell_data[cell_count].includes(searchKey) && cell_count == 0){
          break;
        }
          table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });

});

</script>
```

> Keep in mind that this solution only works if you're going to search within the first column only

Comment: Hi,Thanks for that it's really helpful. :) Ideally Id like to try and search by an ID or by surname, but I'll try and have a go at adding that myself.

Comment: If you could do that please post the code after adding it

Comment: Will do, might be a while though :)

Comment: Actually I've just run into a problem....The PC I use for this at work isn't running the code via Firefox (older version) as it was at home (latest version). Instead Im getting an error: 

TypeError: cell_data[cell_count].includes is not a function

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running it on a localhost using xampp or wamp

Comment: Hmm I don't have permissions to be able to do that. Never mind, thanks for your help :)